# Delete file inside docker container using java

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker

I have below code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
try{
  String[] arguments = new String[] {"rm","-rf", "/home/test1"};
  Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(arguments).start();
 }catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I am copying this file inside docker container named "java-project" and compiling/executing it using this command:

```
docker exec -i java-project bash -c "cd /tmp; cat > $1.java;javac $1.java;java $1" < /tmp/$1.java
```

The docker container has a folder "/home/test1" but it doesn't delete when  java program is executed using docker exec command. But when I manually run the java program by logging in to docker container it deletes the folder.

I checked the program is executed by docker exec but doesn't delete the file.

Edit: Docker container is by default run as root so no need of sudo

Comment: Anything useful if you do `docker log < containerId >` ?

Comment: I just found out it actually deletes the file on the main host instead of docker container.